# ```curl: (52) Empty reply from server``` ERROR response from aws ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ecr

I am trying to make a curl request to get ECR Authorization token instead of using aws cli.
I referred https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/APIReference/API_GetAuthorizationToken.html

And to generate signature, I referred this : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html

```
curl -v --location --request POST 'https://ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443' -H 'Accept-Encoding: identity' -H 'Content-Length: 1590' -H 'X-Amz-Target: AmazonEC2ContainerRegistry_V20150921.GetAuthorizationToken' -H 'X-Amz-Date: 20151129T221940Z' -H 'User-Agent: aws-cli/1.17.14 Python/2.7.5 Linux/3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64 botocore/1.14.14' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1' -H 'Authorization: AUTHPARAMS {AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIA*******/20200514/ap-south-1/ecr/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, Signature=ffe96d25bba760d7502993a1dbf0*********************}'
```

Response returned after few minutes is :

```
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I basically want to use this token in making a curl request to return ECR image tags:

```
curl -i -s -H "Authorization: Basic TOKEN" https://90********.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/v2/image-name/tags/list
```

If i can request the image tags using above command without Token generation....please provide the answer.

Answer (score 0):

this error means that you are receiving a `502 response error`, bad gateway. I had a similar when tried to run a curl command via ssh inside an instance hosted on EC2, so I figured out that I had deployed my image with the port mappings incorrectly. I would recommend you to check the following:

- Check if your security group allows traffic on port 433
- Check if you have deployed your container with the port mappings correctly to ECR, like this:

suppose you have an image called list

To run in your local machine you should execute the following command

`docker run -d -p 80:433 list`

make sure you have mapped these ports correctly on your Dockerfile, then tag your image

`docker tag list 90********.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/v2/image-name/tags/list`

and push to ECR

`docker push 90********.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/v2/image-name/tags/list`

once you have your image pushed to ECR you can run it

`docker run -d -p 80:433 90********.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/v2/image-name/tags/list`

and then you can curl your image

`curl http://ecr-image/your/path`